# Is HP Spectre USB-C Travel Dock are compatible with Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: hp, usb-c, dockstation

I just moved to a new office and there I use my HP x360 Spectre 13t Laptop with Ubuntu 19.04 on board. Works perfectly!

I’m a developer and I want to use a monitor and wireless keyboard at work via dock station.

I found a HP spectre USB-C Travel Dock on HP.com( [Link](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-spectre-usb-c%E2%84%A2-travel-dock) ), but I need to be sure that it is support Ubuntu 19.04 before I buy it.

May be somebody know answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The link is broken. There seem to be different spectre USB-C travel docks. If your laptop supports thunderbolt3, look for an appropriate docking station. Don't buy a docking station using USB 3.0 (no matter whether USB-C or USB-A). Although the hardware will probably be by DisplayLink and there are Linux drivers available, the experience will be disappointing compared to a real DisplayPort output via USB-C.

Comment: Sorry for broken link, fixed. I don’t need a DisplayPort, because monitor doesn’t have 4K resolution. HDMI will be good for me.

Comment: The specs in the HP store are lacking the USB PD standard, but charging will probably work (to be sure, ask HP). All of the other connections/ports are supported by Linux natively, including the display output.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was really helpful